# Dual problem for a problem with strange constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, constraint-programming

I am struggling to find the dual problem for a given primal problem:

$$
(1) \qquad  \underset {x}{\text{minimize}} \hspace{0.4cm} f_0(x)  \\
\qquad s.t. \hspace{0.3cm} y = F_n x
$$
where $x$ is **continuous-time** signal which is a weighted superposition of spikes:
$$
(2) \qquad x = \sum_j a_j \delta_{t_j} .
$$
$F_n$ is the linear map collecting the lowest $n=2f_c+1 $ frequency coefficients ($f_c$ is an integer). In fact the constraint of the above problem is a matrix notation to relate the data $y$ and the object $x$ in the following equation:
$$
(3) \qquad y(k) = \int_0^1 e^{-i2\pi kt}x dt = \sum_ja_je^{-i2\pi kt_j} \hspace{0.3cm} ,\hspace{1cm}  k \in \mathbb{Z},|k|\leq f_c .
$$

The constraint is a little bit strange so that I can not form the Lagrange dual function. I kind of don't know what to do.

Comment: continuous-in-time and superposition of Diracs/spices is somehow contradictory in itself

Comment: Humm ... can $F_n$ really be a linear map ?